# Arrange SVG's in a half circle using React Native SVG

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I am trying to design a React Native UI that has an image in the center and a bunch of buttons around it arranged in a circular motion.

[image: Example Design]

I am using the following formula to compute the placement of the circular buttons

cx:
    cx={Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * i) * circleRadius}

cy:
    cy={Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * i) * circleRadius}

My SVG render
    const circleRadius = Dimensions.get('window').width / 2;
    const numberOfPoints = 8;

```
<Svg style={{flex: 1}}>
  <G>
    <Circle key={0} r="6" cx={Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 0) * circleRadius} cy={Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 0) * circleRadius} fill="green"/>
    <Circle key={1} r="6" cx={Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 1) * circleRadius} cy={Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 1) * circleRadius} fill="purple"/>
    <Circle key={2} r="6" cx={Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 2) * circleRadius} cy={Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 2) * circleRadius} fill="black"/>
    <Circle key={3} r="6" cx={Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 3) * circleRadius} cy={Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 3) * circleRadius} fill="green"/>
    <Circle key={4} r="6" cx={Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 4) * circleRadius} cy={Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 4) * circleRadius} fill="purple"/>
    <Circle key={5} r="6" cx={Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 5) * circleRadius} cy={Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 5) * circleRadius} fill="black"/>
    <Circle key={6} r="6" cx={Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 6) * circleRadius} cy={Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 6) * circleRadius} fill="green"/>
    <Circle key={7} r="6" cx={Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 7) * circleRadius} cy={Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / numberOfPoints * 7) * circleRadius} fill="purple"/>
```

Results in 3 circles in what would be the bottom right portion of the circle rather than the top left portion as in the mock-up

[image: iOS Simulator Screen Cap]

How would I render the circles in a circular fashion as seen in the design?  Is there an easier/better way to accomplish this without using `react-native-svg`?